# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Известная продукция марки Lacoste уже давно получила признание у людей(,) как легкая и удобная одежда для неофициальных встреч и отдыха.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не требуется. В данном контексте подразумевается, что продукция марки Lacoste получила признание **в качестве** легкой и удобной одежды для неофициальных встреч и отдыха. Подробнее про обособление конструкций, вводимых словом "как" можете почитать на форуме "Грамота.ру" либо в другом источнике. Если необходимо что-либо объяснить, обратитесь в комментарии к данному ответу.